# Where should I place my default.realm database file?

Tags: swift, database, realm

I currently have my default.realm file in a folder *assets* in the project directory. When I run my app on device I get permission error below, this is not on simulator

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an 
error: Error 
Domain=io.realm Code=2"Unable to open a realm at path 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BD313F74-303C-4A58- 
9CA9- 
6FF5C6851A3B/AXIMATOR.app/default.realm.lock': open() failed: Operation not 
permittedPath: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BD313F74-303C-4A58-9CA9- 
6FF5C6851A3B/AXIMATOR.app/default.realm.lock
```

Here is my realm initialization

```
let docDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: 
.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
let realmUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "realm")
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmUrl)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

I have copied the default.realm file to *.documentDirectory* where I stil get permission error below

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an 
error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=2 "Unable to open a realm at 
path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2445658F-A925-48B9- 
AA04-6568FC8AC7C9/Documents.lock': open() failed: Operation not 
permitted Path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2445658F- 
A925-48B9-AA04-6568FC8AC7C9/Documents.lock
```

What is the ideal location to place my realm file? I already have a ready-made realm file

Comment: @Sweeper exactly my realm file already contains data so I am currently placing it in my projects folder and getting the error above. I have tried copying it [like these](https://www.codepile.net/pile/3Mm3YRz6) but the error persists

Comment: Also include the new code that you tried and the new error message!

Comment: Where you place it depends on what you want to do with it; the default location is usually the best idea, so why do you want to move it or have it elsewhere? It also looks like you are attempting to include a bundled realm and if that's the case, it will be read only and will exist within the app bundle, so you don't need to put it anywhere as it will be part of the project. Can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this using *fileURL* instead of *configuration* parameter

```
let realm  = try! Realm(fileURL: inDocumentDirectory(fileName: "default.realm"))
```

Function *inDocumentDirectory()* is what am using to load the file URL

```
func inDocumentDirectory(fileName: String) -> URL {
    
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0], isDirectory: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(fileName)
}
```

This is for when you ship pre bundle data with the application since bundle data is read only you can’t modify it and if you want to modify that data, you need to move this data to some writable location. You can copy your pre bundle realm file using the method below, you can optimize by adding a file exists check so as to copy only the first time

```
func copyFilesFromBundleToDocumentsFolderWith(fileExtension: String) {
    if let resPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath {
        do {
            let dirContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: resPath)
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
            let filteredFiles = dirContents.filter{ $0.contains(fileExtension)}
            for fileName in filteredFiles {
                if let documentsURL = documentsURL {
                    let sourceURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    let destURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: destURL)
                    } catch CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile {
                        print("name, No such file")
                    } catch let error {
                        // other errors
                        print("name: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch { }
    }
}
```